# how should I access aws-sdk-php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

that is My code for uploading to the S3 bucket.
I'm calling

```
require ('../../vendor/autoload.php');
use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
```

after that I'm setting my bucket info.

```
   $bucket = 'my-bucket-name';
   // // Create an S3 client instance
   $s3Client = new S3Client([
   'version'     => 'latest',
   'region'      => 'eu-central-1',
   ]);
```

and when I'm executing

```php
$result = $s3Client->putObject([
  'Bucket'     => $bucket,
  'Key'        => $uploadfile,
  'SourceFile' => $filePath,
  ]);
```

I'm getting error :

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found in.

I do have an autoload.php in my

```
/var/www/html/vendor
```

but my aws-sdk-php is installed at

```
/home/ec2-user/vendor/aws
```

and when I'm doing require to this folder I'm getting this Error :

> "failed to open stream: Permission denied.

should I move the SDK ?
there are some dependencies ?

Comment: Run composer from the "root" of your project, not your home directory.

Comment: Ok, so shell I remove the current installation ?

Comment: You can delete the files in ec2-user, yes.